# No puedo conectar mi base de datos MySQL con mis migraciones

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, base-de-datos

tardes o noches. Tengo un problema al intentar usar Laravel.
Siendo más específico, tengo una base de datos en MySQL, siendo el de la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También utilice Laravel para poder crear las migraciones, siendo las de la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que deseo realizar es conectar la base de datos que cree manualmente con las migraciones. Observe que se crea la base de datos al ejecutar las migraciones, pero no deseo eso, por ende, cree la base de datos primero; además, que varias personas recomendaron esto.
Mi archivo ".env" es este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me mencionaron que igualmente debía modificar el archivo de "database.php" de la carpeta "config":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al final de cuentas, debería poder conectarse a la base de datos, pero esto no es así. Me da un error que es el siguiente:

```
   INFO  Running migrations.  

  2019_12_14_000001_create_personal_access_tokens_table .................................................................................. 69ms DONE
  2024_02_15_160049_create_permissions_table .............................................................................................. 1ms FAIL

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'permissions' already exists (Connection: mysql, SQL: create table `permissions` (`permission_id` bigint unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `permission_name` varchar(255) not null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

  at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:829
    825▕                     $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    826▕                 );
    827▕             }
    828▕
  ➜ 829▕             throw new QueryException(
    830▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    831▕             );
    832▕         }
    833▕     }
```

Probé revisando tutoriales, documentación sobre esto, pero sin ningún resultado. Probe también el ejecutar el comando primero antes de "php artisan migrate":

> "php artisan migrate:install"

Hacer esto me salió el mensaje de:

```
   INFO  Migration table created successfully.
```

Volví a ejecutar las migraciones, pero me seguía arrojando el mismo resultado. Quisiera que me ayudasen a resolver este dilema mío. Y si preguntan, revise incluso la tabla, migraciones, la base de datos al crearse la migración y sigue con ese problema.

Comment: Lee el mensaje de error *"Base table or view already exists..."*. Si te dice que a tabla que intentas crear ya existe, es porque se puede "conectar", si no se pudiese conectar, no podria saber que la tabla ya existe. Te sugieroo leer la documentacion de laravel https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#rolling-back-migrations

Comment: Tu App si tiene conexión con la base de datos porque empieza a ejecutar las migraciones, inlcuso detecta que quieres crear tablas que ya existen. Lo que te sugiero es que crees todas las tablas a través de **Laravel** y así cuando modifiques algún campo o migración puedas actualizar la base de datos de la siguiente manera `php artisan migrate:fresh`, esto hará que se eliminen todas las tablas de la BD y se vuelva a ejecutar las migraciones.